# Is it possible to detect drag in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I wanted to know if there is any event in Jquery Mobile that let you hide/show div by dragging it Like the effect in the phone.

I have researched in stack and the nearest solution I found was by using `Jquery UI` can it be done by just using the JqueryMobile function ??.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Why don't you want to use Jquery UI?

Comment: @Manwal okay i will try to use it and come up with some Fiddle . Actually already I am using JQM events and I am very new to Jquery stuff so for me it was complicated to use both of them together .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can with Jquery UI,

I created a Demo for you, so just drag the box about center on screen and it will hide.

http://jsfiddle.net/JEV5T/

```
var coordinates = function(element) {
    element = $(element);
    var top = element.position().top;
    var left = element.position().left;
    $('#results').text('X: ' + left + ' ' + 'Y: ' + top);

    // If the box position is greater than 133px from left then hide it

    if (left > 133) {
     $("#box").hide();   
    }
}


$('#box').draggable({
    start: function() {
        coordinates('#box');
    },
    stop: function() {
        coordinates('#box');
    }
});
```

If you want to hide a different element while moving the box the change the ($("#box").hide();)  to the name of the div element. Also you can add another (if) statement to unhide it.

Taken from here on how to get the coordinates of a div using JQ UI.
http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-getting-the-coordinates-of-a-draggable-object/

Comment: Does this work with touch response ??. Because what I read from the Jq Ui documentation is that it works only with mouse :)

Comment: yes I read about it too :) thanks man . So one last consultation . ie Is it a good move to to add JQ Ui and JQM all together ??

Comment: If you refactore it works like a charm, so choose only the components you need, in this case just Dragable -- http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Cheers, it should be ok, but as i said, customize the JQ UI and just choose only Interactions like Draggable/Droppable etc. Widgets and themes etc may not work well JQM on mobile devices. I'm not sure about effects. Its easy to do a test anyway.

Comment: bro I have this http://jsfiddle.net/YcW2V/ fiddle where I used Jquery to develop a simple slide on button click . So what I am trying to do is I wanted to make this effect work on touch-drag . Like I could touch the button and drag the menu back/forth also being able to work with the click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57370/discussion-between-vikram-and-tasos).